# How to copy multiple cells between notebooks in ObservableHQ?

Tags: observablehq

It seems I can COPY the cells by selecting one and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> etc ... check marks appear on all the cell, I can copy it, but then pasting just dumps everything into one cell. And I think the ObservableHQ model is some weird single await per cell. You can not have more than "one line" of code per cell.

How to paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy multiple cells, the clipboard holds different versions for different contexts:

- The plaintext version, for pasting into any regular text field or text editor
- The Observable application version, for pasting cells between notebooks as cells

If your keyboard focus is inside a cell editor in another notebook, the clipboard treats that as a plaintext context, so it'll just paste the code all lumped together.

To paste the cells as cells, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> so that a blue border appears around the cell (the same kind of focus state in which you originally selected the cells) and *then* paste.

(I work at Observable; copying and pasting cells is a new feature, and we could probably improve it with some auto-detection.)